# How i can use yeoman to work with Sass files?

Tags: sass, gruntjs, yeoman

I try to use yeoman to compile a styles.sass file founded in app/styles directory.

In my index.html i write :

```
<!-- build:css(.tmp/styles) styles/styles.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.sass" />
<!-- endbuild -->
```

When i launch grunt server

Sass file is watched and compiled into

.tmp/styles/

But in my dist/styles directory, nothing is written in my xxxxxxx.styles.css

may i miss something?

Comment: Might be better to ask in the Yeoman `IRC` channel - http://yeoman.io/generators.html#get-help

Comment: Also note that there are 2 ways to do Sass - the .sass and .scss the latter being the newer maybe better one? I got some compile errors using sass watch using the former..  way.http://thesassway.com/editorial/sass-vs-scss-which-syntax-is-better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Sass is compiled into `.tmp/styles` when running `grunt server`, since it's only temporary. This is done so not to create a mess of compiled CSS files in your `app` directory. When you run `grunt` it will compile it to the `dist/styles` folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When i run grunt it compile it to the .tmp/styles. It create the file in dist/styles but nothing inside.  I edit my first message to show you the command in my index.html. I have the default grunt.js of yeoman 1.0.

Comment: @kalaoke Try `<!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css --><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css"><!-- endbuild -->` -- In the case of Sass files, your `<link>` should point to the generated css file.