# Yeoman: Add sass/compass support in grunt to existing project

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs, yeoman

I have an existing project, but I need to add sass/compass so that grunt will automatically compile it when I use the `grunt server` command.

Does anyone know how I do this?

Edit: I've managed to add grunt sas/compasss to the project, but I need to configure gruntfile.js to watch and compile the css. All I've done to add sass support is to run `npm install grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev`.

Comment: @TJonS I've managed to add grunt sass to the project, but I need to configure gruntfile.js to watch and compile the css.

Comment: Have you tried to do it at all yourself? If so, please share what you've done.

Comment: I used yeoman to set up the project, but didn't add sass/compass support. All I've done to add sass support is `npm install grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev`.

Comment: Why don't you add the support? Or, you should at least try!

Comment: This question may be a duplicate. [Here is the previous question;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213242/how-i-can-use-yeoman-to-work-with-sass-files?rq=1) It may help.

Comment: @TJonS I am trying. And no, his sass compilation is working, he was just referencing the wrong file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/p-j/6340992) of a `Gruntfile.js` I'm using for a project that does SASS compilation and a handfull of other things.

It's inspired of [Yeoman's webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp) generated `Gruntfile.js`, with BlessCSS and Assemble, Htmlmin configured to run smoothly with Usemin and Coffee/Mocha stuff commented out.

Basically, what you need to do is config the `SASS` task and then add it to the watch task, and setup livereload to watch your `CSS` files.

---

**Edit:**

Since I was using this `Gruntfile` and these `grunt tasks` pretty often, I've since made a `yeoman generator` that you can checkout here : [p-j/generator-yawa](https://github.com/p-j/generator-yawa)

It does sass/compass among other things.